# How to define onStart method in scala play framework 2.4

Tags: scala, akka, playframework-2.4

how can i define startup job in play framework 2.4 with scala?
[play framework GlobalSetting](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GlobalSettings)
I have already:

```
class StartupConfigurationModule extends AbstractModule{

  override def configure(): Unit = {
    Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(Duration(0,duration.HOURS),Duration(24,duration.HOURS))(Id3Service.start())
    Akka.system.dispatcher
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register this in the `modules.enabled` of your application (in `application.conf`).

It should schedule a call to start on the Id3Service after 0 hours and then every 24 hours.

The issue is that the module doesn't declare a dependency on a running application, or more interestingly on a started actorSystem. Guice can decide to start it before the app is initialized.

The follwing is one way to force the dependency on the initialized actorSystem (and reduce the footprint of your dependency)

```
import javax.inject.{ Singleton, Inject }

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class StartupConfigurationModule extends AbstractModule {

  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[Schedule]).asEagerSingleton()
  }

}

@Singleton
class Schedule @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem) {
  implicit val ec = actorSystem.dispatcher
  actorSystem.scheduler.schedule(Duration(0, HOURS), Duration(24, HOURS))(Id3Service.start())
}
object Id3Service {
  def start(): Unit = println("started")
}
```

Comment: sorry, i want to schedule this task every 24 hours

Comment: well your updated code should do it, what is the issue ?

Comment: well, thanks for the suggest. I've added this into conf file play.modules.enabled += "controllers.StartupConfigurationModule" but not work. I get this error    CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: There is no started application
  at com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule.configure(Modules.java:177)

Comment: I need to create a scheduler on start up of my application, can you suggest me an easy way to do this?
Registering modules i got 
1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: There is no started application
  at com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule.configure(Modules.java:177)